# what is the best way to proceed for impementing Elasticsearch in my project using JAVA?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am totally new to elasticseach and I have made some dummy applications also by following two procedures->

1>Using **Spring data elasticsearch**(In which I don't need to run elasticsearch in the background),Just by importing the **ElasticsearchRepository** I can make crud operations.

But here I am facing one problem that - I need to make different model classes for each type of data(let's say UserModel and UserAddressModel) with some fields(which will be static). So, if later I need to add a new data in that type I need to add that field in the model class also.

So, can we make that dynamic???

2>And in another application I have used **JAVA TransportClient** by which I can make crud operations and can save any data (not using a model here) and I can add new field dynamically also.

So, I am pretty confused that which is the best way for proceeding further according to performance wise in production level? or both are same?

Using **TransportClient**:

```
public class UserResource {

TransportClient client;

public UserResource() throws UnknownHostException {
    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

}

@GetMapping("/insert/{id}")
public String insert(@PathVariable final String id) throws IOException {

    IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("employee", "id", id)
            .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("fname", "peter")
                    .field("lname", "parker")
                    .field("salary", 1200)
                    .field("teamName", "Development")
                    .endObject()
            )
            .get();
    return response.getResult().toString();
}


@GetMapping("/view/{id}")
public Map<String, Object> view(@PathVariable final String id) {
    GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet("employee", "id", id).get();
    System.out.println(getResponse.getSource());


    return getResponse.getSource();
}

@GetMapping("/update/{id}")
public String update(@PathVariable final String id) throws IOException {

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
    updateRequest.index("employee")
            .type("id")
            .id(id)
            .doc(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("gender", "male")
                    .endObject());
    try {
        UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.update(updateRequest).get();
        System.out.println(updateResponse.status());
        return updateResponse.status().toString();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "Exception";
}

@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable final String id) {

    DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.prepareDelete("employee", "id", id).get();

    System.out.println(deleteResponse.getResult().toString());
    return deleteResponse.getResult().toString();
}
}
```

Using **Springdata Elasticsearch**:

```
public class SearchQueryBuilder {

@Autowired
private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;


public List<Users> getAll(String text) {

    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(
                    QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(text)
                            .lenient(true)
                            .field("name")
                            .field("teamName")
            ).should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*" + text + "*")
                    .lenient(true)
                    .field("name")
                    .field("teamName"));

    NativeSearchQuery build = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(query)
            .build();

    List<Users> userses = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(build, Users.class);

    return userses;
}
```

DATA Loader:

```
public class Loaders {

@Autowired
ElasticsearchOperations operations;

@Autowired
UsersRepository usersRepository;

@Autowired
VideoRepository videoRepository;

@PostConstruct
@Transactional
public void loadAll(){


    operations.putMapping(Users.class);
    operations.putMapping(Videos.class);
    usersRepository.save(getData());
    videoRepository.save(getVideoData());

}

private List<Users> getData() {
    List<Users> userses = new ArrayList<>();
    userses.add(new Users("peter",123L, "Accounting", 12000L));

    return userses;
}
```

User **Model**:

```
@Document(indexName = "new", type = "users", shards = 1)
public class Users {

private String name;
private Long id;
private String teamName;
private Long salary;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}

public Long getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(Long salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

User **Repository**:

```
public interface UsersRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Users, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Please understand that your question boils down to "please help me resolving my complex problem". But we do not regard such requests as valid questions (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) for details). The intent of this community is to help with specific problems, not to outline a map for you that takes you through a complex scenario to a final vague vision ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Java application, then High Level Java REST client is the way to go (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/index.html).

Please note that TransportClient has been deprecated and support will be dropped in v. 8 (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/master/transport-client.html). So that consideration alone would be more important than any performance considerations.

Choice between static and dynamic mapping is a fundamental one -- nothing per se to do with Spring elasticsearch. If you have dynamic mapping, you could consider using a dynamic template and do away with providing field mapping.

In the past, Spring ES project has been a bit slow to catch up with ES version, so be aware that your capability to upgrade ES versions might be affected if you use Spring data ES.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @senseiwu.